# React Styled Components - Gradient

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

How can I add css gradient to styled component?

```
background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle cover, red 0, blue 100%);
```

Comment: Have you considered using google?

Comment: @ndugger but google isn't a react component

Comment: @KevinB `class Google extends React.Component { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gradients in styled-components are the same as in regular CSS, but your gradient syntax seems to be invalid – for example the `cover` keyword [was only in early browser implementations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient#Values) many years ago. Try this instead:

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at center, red 0, blue 100%);
```

Read [Using radial gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients#Using_radial_gradients) on MDN for more details.

Also, DevTools (right click > inspect element) will tell you when there is something wrong with your styles:

[image]